# How to reuse NerdTree core function with API?

Tags: vim, nerdtree

I'm looking for a way to reuse core nerdtree functions on NERDTreeAddKeyMap callback function but i did not find a way to do it after looking up on net.

I tried a few things like the one bellow :

```
call NERDTreeAddKeyMap({                                                         
  \ 'key': '<Left>',                                                             
  \ 'scope': 'Node',                                                             
  \ 'callback': 'NerdTest' })                                                    

function! NerdTest(node)                                                         
  call closeCurrentDir(a:node)                                                                                                                                                                           
endfunction
```

But i hit this error when trying to press  on a directory

```
E117: Unknown function: closeCurrentDir
```

Any suggestions ?

Best regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [closeCurrentDir function](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree/blob/49c165a1036415e8de038d257adb3735535b6b17/autoload/nerdtree/ui_glue.vim#L186-L205) is a script-local one; it is not exposed to the outside.

There are hacks to make it accessible, or you could ask the author to expose it as an [`:help autoload`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#autoload) function.

However, as that function is mapped to a key ([`:help NERDTree-x`](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree/blob/c1b71dcfc5aaf9140361a1631a06a9dd5c88e526/doc/NERDTree.txt#L374-L379)), you can just trigger that key via `:normal`. If you use the corresponding config variable (`g:NERDTreeMapCloseDir`) instead of hard-coding the key, this even allows for remappings.

```
function! NerdTest(node)
    execute 'normal' g:NERDTreeMapCloseDir
endfunction
```

Comment: Wasn't aware we could use those mappings as this. If I only need functions already mapped it seems to do the job. Thanks :)